# Merge multiple audio into one video

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

```
func mergeAudioFiles(audioFileUrls: NSMutableArray,completion: @escaping (URL)-> Swift.Void) {

    let composition = AVMutableComposition()

    for i in 0 ..< audioFileUrls.count {

        let compositionAudioTrack :AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: ((audioFileUrls[i] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["soundURL"] as! URL))

        let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeMake(0, 600), duration: CMTime(seconds: Double((audioFileUrls[i] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["time"] as! CGFloat), preferredTimescale: track.timeRange.duration.timescale))

        try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: track, at: composition.duration)
    }



    let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
    self.mergeAudioURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("audio.m4a")! as URL

    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport?.outputURL = mergeAudioURL as URL
    removeFileAtURLIfExists(url: mergeAudioURL)
    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler:
        {
            switch assetExport!.status
            {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(String(describing: assetExport?.error))")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(String(describing: assetExport?.error))")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                print("unknown\(String(describing: assetExport?.error))")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                print("waiting\(String(describing: assetExport?.error))")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                print("exporting\(String(describing: assetExport?.error))")
            default:
                print("-----Merge audio exportation complete.\(self.mergeAudioURL)")

                completion(self.mergeAudioURL)

            }
    })
}
```

So i am recording users button data into a array of dictionary, the dictionary has "soundURL" - i am passing url of the sound depending on which button was pressed and "time" at what time the button was pressed, example if i start audio recording and user presses button red after 2.13 seconds it will pass ["soundURL":redURL,"time":2:13]

The problem here in the code is if i tap on buttons very fast (like 10 times in 2 seconds) it creates the audio file of 10 seconds as the sound is 1 seconds, what i want it to do is, last audio should stop as soon as the new button is pressed. so it should merge like that not in a queqe but all together